# Configure next-i18next with NextJS and Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, i18next

Using the next-i18next library on NextJS and Typescript I encountered the problem reported at the bottom. How can I fix it? I also uploaded the code of the files where I use the library, nothing special.

_app.tsx

```
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next"

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

index.tsx

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ locales }:{locales: string}) => {
    return {
        props: { ...(await serverSideTranslations(locales, ['common'])) }
    };
};
```

next-i18next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      locales: ['en', 'it']
    },
}
```

next.config.js

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

module.exports = {
    i18n
}
```

ERROR:

```
 Error: Initial locale argument was not passed into serverSideTranslations
enter code here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter name is locale not locales
. You're passing current locale not all locales. My code snippet

index.tsx

```
 import { getStaticPropsTranslations } from '@/utils/i18n'    
 export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }: { locale: string }) {
    return {
        props: {
            ...(await getStaticPropsTranslations(locale)),
        },
    }
}
```

@/utils/i18n.ts

```
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations'

export const getStaticPropsTranslations = async (locale: string) => {
      return {
         ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['instructions',])),
      }
}
```